How to remove a cap from a pex supply
I am trying to install a cup sprayer and need to know how to remove this black cap from supply line. This is a supply line, right?


That may be a supply. If it is you need to be sure the water is off before removing it.  If it is a pex cap, The pipe needs to be cut below the cap.

@RMDman  Almost a full answer.

Being under a kitchen sink, if the cold water is already connected I would guess a second cold water line was run to plan for a water softener either installed or to allow for it in the future. I also see an escutcheon just visible under the food disposal... is there a third pipe coming up under the cabinet?

There is a third pipe that is for cleaning out i believe.

@BabyBlues I've never seen a PEX cleanout. Cleanouts are for drain pipes.\

Cut the pipe just below the cap. To reuse the cap, cut the ring with a copper ring removal tool, and remove the plug. If you don't have the tool, a hacksaw will do.

Just remember the golden rule: Never start a plumbing project after the store has closed.

@spuck So true.

You'd know better than we would what's the purpose of that pipe. I assume it's a cold water supply from its location.
Cut the tube to remove the cap. Something like that's intended to be temporary and disposable.
